# UIImageView.animationImages displaying images with rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView that should animate an array of images called `capturedImages`. I have the animation set up like so:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 48, 320, 520);
imageView.animationImages = capturedImages;


imageView.animationDuration = 3.0;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; //animate forever
[imageView startAnimating];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

The images in capturedImages are taken with the phone/camera view upright. However, when the imageView displays them, they animate properly but are rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. Is there a way to change the orientation of `animationImages`, or do I have to set each image's orientation individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to just rotate the `UIImageView` itself.
You can use the `transform` property of `UIView` to do this:

```
[imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];
```

Be aware of the fact that this will break if you start displaying images which are already in the correct orientation. These will be rotated 90 degrees clockwise as well.

Comment: This works for rotating the pictures, but with the above dimensions for imageView.frame the animation is distorted. How does performing a CGAffineTransform affect how you should draw the bounds of the image view's frame?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `image` property for the `UIImageView` to the first image in the list of images fixes the problem. For example in my view controller (swift):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let images = self.images {
        if images.count > 0 {
            self.animation_view.image = images[0]
        }

        self.animation_view.animationImages = images
        self.animation_view.animationRepeatCount = 0
        self.animation_view.animationDuration = 1.0
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.animation_view.startAnimating()
}
```